# How to link an external library in Qt Creator when LIBS += -L"..." doesn't seem to work?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, qt-creator, raytracing

I've been trying to use the [Intel Open Image Denoise](https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn) library in my code but still have no luck as of now. Apparently it seems that I am not linking the library properly.

Here's what I've done so far: after compiling OIDN I moved the oidn directory to the directory where my path tracer code is and did the following in my code (C++11) which I'm working on in Qt Creator.

```
#include "oidn/include/OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp"
.
.
.
oidn::DeviceRef device = oidn::newDevice(); // this is where things break
device.commit();
```

Note that doing `#include "oidn/include/OpenImageDenoise/oidn.hpp"` seems to work fine because autocomplete works for oidn and shows its members. However I get the following errors which seems to be due to not linking oidn libraries.

[image]

I tried linking the libraries via `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/"` or `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/libOpenImageDenoise.so"` (as shown in the image) but I get the same errors. I also appended `-loidn` but got an error saying `"cannot find -loidn"`. I am now pretty confused on what I'm supposed to do. I'm not even sure if the errors are due to not properly linking libraries because I see people generally link libraries in C++ the same way I am trying to do it here. I would really appreciate if someone can help me figure out what I need to do to get OIDN work.

Comment: `-L` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: @user253751 Could you be more specific? What could be the problem then?

Comment: You can try adding the library directly using Qt Creator. https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Comment: Probably you need `-L oidn/build` (path where some libraries could be found) then `-lOpenImageDenoise` (name of the required library  without `lib` and `.so`)

Comment: There are usually two command line options for linking libraries: `-L` (big L) to denote library _directories_ and `-l` (small L) to denote libraries to link (which are searched in the mentioned library directories).

Comment: @prog-fh Thanks. Tried your recommendation but got the error `cannot find -loidn/build/libOpenImageDenoise.so`

Comment: Where does this `-loidn/build/libOpenImageDenoise.so` come from? I wrote `-lOpenImageDenoise`.

Comment: @prog-fh It comes after compiling OpenImageDenoise. It is located in `oidn/build` directory

Comment: Yes but the **option** itself (starting with `-l`) you must have written it somewhere... Just try `-L oidn/build -lOpenImageDenoise` as explained in my comment above.

Comment: I just tried `-L oidn/build -lOpenImageDenoise` and I get the error `cannot find -llOpenImageDenoise` :/ What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you wrote two `l` instead of one...

Comment: @prog-fh No I did not. This is precisely the command I used: `LIBS += -L oidn/build -lOpenImageDenoise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the previous answers/comments were correct. The weird thing about my case was the symlinks of the libraries in the `build` directory were not valid and were not pointing to the right files. The output of `ls -lh /home/Warrior/Desktop/pathtracer/oidn/build` was as follow:

```
total 160K
drwxrwxr-x 4 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 apps
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  19K Feb  4 00:09 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 7 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 6.5K Feb  4 00:09 cmake_install.cmake
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 common
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.6K Feb  4 00:09 CPackConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:09 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 103K Feb  4 00:09 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  4 00:08 mkl-dnn
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 1.6K Feb  4 00:09 OpenImageDenoiseConfigVersion.cmake
```

But when I would go to the directory I would see the following:

[image]

What I did was instead of cloning the oidn repo somewhere else and building it, I cloned the oidn repo in `/home/Warrior/Desktop/pathtracer/` and built it there. After that I could see the correct file names/symlinks via `ls -lh` as follow. Now my program compiles and things work fine. I just had to use `LIBS += -L"oidn/build/" -lOpenImageDenoise` when compiling my code:

```
total 51M
drwxrwxr-x 4 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 apps
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  19K Feb  9 10:14 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x 7 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:19 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 5.6K Feb  9 10:14 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 color_ispc_sse4.h
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 common
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.3K Feb  9 10:14 CPackConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 3.7K Feb  9 10:14 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.6K Feb  9 10:17 input_reorder_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  41K Feb  9 10:14 libcommon.a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  16M Feb  9 10:17 libdnnl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 amir amir   24 Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so -> libOpenImageDenoise.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 amir amir   28 Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so.0 -> libOpenImageDenoise.so.1.3.0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir  34M Feb  9 10:19 libOpenImageDenoise.so.1.3.0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir  37K Feb  9 10:19 libutils.a
drwxrwxr-x 2 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:17 local__core
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 104K Feb  9 10:14 Makefile
drwxrwxr-x 3 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:14 mkl-dnn
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir 181K Feb  9 10:19 oidnBenchmark
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir  59K Feb  9 10:19 oidnDenoise
-rwxrwxr-x 1 amir amir 882K Feb  9 10:19 oidnTest
-rw-r--r-- 1 amir amir 1.6K Feb  9 10:14 OpenImageDenoiseConfigVersion.cmake
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.9K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_copy_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 3.1K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 2.5K Feb  9 10:17 output_reorder_ispc_sse4.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_avx2.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_avx512skx.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.8K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amir amir 1.5K Feb  9 10:17 upsample_ispc_sse4.h
drwxrwxr-x 2 amir amir 4.0K Feb  9 10:17 weights
```